# minimum variance hedge with stochastic processes

Tags: finance, variance, quantitative, hedge

Problem set up:

asset S: $$\frac{dS}{S} = \mu dt+\sigma dz$$
Hedged using a forward contract: $F = F(S,t).$
Hedge portfolio: $$P = S+nF$$
I want to find the variance of $dP$, and then minimize that with respect to $n$, to calculate the optimal number of forward contracts.

$$dP = dS + ndF;$$ $dF$ uses Ito's Lemma
The variance of the change in the portfolio is defined as follows:
then for $$V(dP) = EdP^2 - (EdP)^2$$
where V stands for Variance and E stands for Expectation, of the Portfolio P
My goal is to find the Variance and then minimize it with respect to n.
Does anyone have experience using the concept of minimum variance hedge ratio in a set up like this? Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I edited to typeset with mathjax for readability. Click on the edit to see how to do it. It's unclear to me what $V,$ $E,$ and lower-case $p$ are (although perhaps lowercase $p$ is just a typo for uppercase). And also it's unclear as a result what you're trying to do in the last line.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check ti out. I'll also make some edits along the lines you suggested to clarify the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ito's lemma gives $$dF = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2 S^2\right)dt + \frac{\partial F}{\partial S}dS = adt + bdS $$

Using the usual rules, e.g. $dz^2 = dt$, we get $$ dS^2 = \sigma^2S^2dt,$$ $$dF^2 = b^2dS^2 = b^2\sigma^2S^2dt,$$ and $$dSdF = bdS^2 = b \sigma^2S^2dt,$$ so this gives  $$dP^2  = dS^2 + n^2dF^2 + 2ndFdS = \sigma^2S^2 (1+n^2b^2+2nb)dt = \sigma^2S^2(nb+1)^2dt.$$

This is the same as the expected value $E(dP^2)$.

Then for the other term, you know that $E (dP)$ is going to be of the form $c dt$ so that $(E(dP))^2 = 0.$

Comment: Man thanks a ton! I was applying Ito's incorrectly, somewhere. I followed your steps to attempt again and got to the right point. My final solution for the minimum variance hedge is then n = -1/b. Are you able to confirm that you get the same?

Comment: @user24392 Yeah that would just be hedging on whatever the delta is between the forward and the underlying is, so it seems like that has to minimize the one-period variance.

Comment: thanks. I need to rethink my problem set up though...I should be getting n = -b, not 1/b. I'll go back to the drawing board for now. thanks again!

Comment: @user24392 No, I think $n = -\frac{1}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial S}}$ makes a lot of sense. (It might seem backwards since usually we frame things as hedging a derivative with the underlying, not the hedging the underlying with the derivative.) Also another potential point of confusion: In this formulation $F$ refers to the *value* of the forward contract... Usually when we say "forward price" and write formulas for it, we don't mean the value of any particular contract, but the strike price that would give a contract value zero.

Comment: "@spaceisdarkgreen": thanks sir. But in the simplest case, say I'm short units of Iron for my  production of widgets. I want to cover my short exposure by buying forward contracts. In this case...am I not hedging the short position in the underlying (iron) with the forward (derivative)? Thanks for being patient....still new at all this and trying to learn myself.

Comment: @user24392 You're right, that is the natural thinking from the perspective of an end user, and I certainly wasn't arguing that was wrong in any way. I was just speculating that maybe the reason you have things turned around is cause in most treatments of derivatives I see it's from the perspective of an options trader, where the underlying is thought of as delta hedging the option. If that's not why, disregard.

Comment: "@spaceisdarkgreen ok, we're on the same page then! Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: revisiting this topic after some time, and I realize I completely missed your point above "This is the same as the expected value E(dP2)". So I "solved" the problem...but am still missing a fundamental piece...could you elaborate please? Is it possibly because "dt" is really a constant/known increment? Thanks!

Comment: @Chet Yes, it is because $dP^2$ is not random.

Comment: thanks sir! and that is because the term "dt" itself is not random - is that correct? thanks for being pateint:)

Comment: @Chet yes, that is right